# Trouble finding odd results of an array

Tags: php

I can't seem to find the answer to these problem. I have the following php code.

```
 $r = 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on
```

and i want to get the number like this

```
 $result = 1,3,5
```

or if i have

```
 $s = b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i...and so on
```

the result should be

```
$results c,e,g,i
```

Comment: Simply check key of array is Even / Odd dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy with numbers, the trick with letters is to use `ord()`

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$arr = array_filter ($arr, function ($number) {
    return $number % 2;
});
print_r($arr);

$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$arr = array_filter ($arr, function ($letter) {
    return ord($letter) % 2;
});
print_r($arr);
```

Output :

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
Array (
    [0] => a
    [2] => c
    [4] => e
)
```

And here is a generic solution, working with both letters and numbers :

```
$arr = array_filter ($arr, function ($value) {
    $value = is_int($value) ? $value : ord($value);
    return $value % 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($a as $k => $v){
    if($k&1){
        unset($a[$k]);
    }
} 
print_r($a);
```